# Mach-O Errors with Parse even AFTER adding FacebookSDK

Tags: facebook, swift, google-maps, parse-platform, mach-o

After adding the Google Maps SDK to my Swift app, I am required to use the -ObjC linker flag.

This of course causes Parse to go insane and reference everything Facebook. After looking online, the solution appears to be to add the FacebookSDK. I've attempted to add it numerous times (dragging FBSDKCoreKit.framework into project), but to no avail. I continue to get the same errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_FBTokenInformationExpirationDateKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy cacheTokenInformation:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy expirationDate] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setExpirationDate:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationTokenKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy accessToken] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setAccessToken:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_FBTokenInformationUserFBIDKey", referenced from:
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy facebookId] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
      -[PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy setFacebookId:] in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBAppCall", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBRequest", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSession", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookAuthenticationProvider.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_CLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "_OBJC_METACLASS_$_FBSessionTokenCachingStrategy", referenced from:
      _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy in ParseFacebookUtils(PFFacebookTokenCachingStrategy.o)
  "std::string::find_first_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::find_first_not_of(char const*, unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::substr(unsigned long, unsigned long) const", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::_Rep::_M_destroy(std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::_Rep::_S_empty_rep_storage", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(bool (*)(void*, int, int, int, unsigned int), void*, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::~ExceptionHandler() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      ...
  "std::string::append(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::append(unsigned long, char)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
  "std::string::assign(char const*, unsigned long)", referenced from:
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::ConvertToString(__CFString const*) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
  "std::string::assign(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::ExceptionHandler(std::string const&, bool (*)(void*), bool (*)(char const*, char const*, void*, bool), void*, bool, char const*) in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ExceptionHandler::UpdateNextID() in ParseCrashReporting(exception_handler.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&)", referenced from:
      BreakpadPFC_::HandleUncaughtException(NSException*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::Initialize(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      BreakpadPFC_::GenerateReport(NSDictionary*) in ParseCrashReporting(Breakpad.o)
      MacStringUtilsPFC_::IntegerValueAtIndex(std::string&, unsigned int) in ParseCrashReporting(string_utilities.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::ReadTaskString(unsigned int, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::UTF16ToUTF8(std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > const&, bool) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(std::string const&)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::WriteModuleStream(unsigned int, MDRawModule*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO64>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      void google_breakpadPFC_::ReadImageInfo<google_breakpadPFC_::MachO32>(google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImages&, unsigned long long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImage::DynamicImage(unsigned char*, unsigned long, unsigned long long, std::string, unsigned long, unsigned int, int) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
  "std::__throw_length_error(char const*)", referenced from:
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<MDMemoryDescriptor*, std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> > >, MDMemoryDescriptor const&) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<MDMemoryDescriptor, google_breakpadPFC_::PageStdAllocator<MDMemoryDescriptor> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::reserve(unsigned long) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> >::_M_insert_aux(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef*, std::vector<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef, std::allocator<google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef> > >, google_breakpadPFC_::DynamicImageRef const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned char*, std::vector<unsigned char, std::allocator<unsigned char> > >, unsigned long, unsigned char const&) in ParseCrashReporting(dynamic_images.o)
      std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> >::_M_fill_insert(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<unsigned short*, std::vector<unsigned short, std::allocator<unsigned short> > >, unsigned long, unsigned short const&) in ParseCrashReporting(string_conversion.o)
  "std::__throw_out_of_range(char const*)", referenced from:
      google_breakpadPFC_::MinidumpGenerator::UniqueNameInDirectory(std::string const&, std::string*) in ParseCrashReporting(minidump_generator.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Am I adding the SDK incorrectly? [Here are the frameworks I have linked.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hc2O7.png)

Comment: try to clean and build

Comment: Cleaning it sadly did not work :(

Answer (score 0):

Look at my answer right [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29788415/parse-and-gmaps-ios-sdk-incompatibility-in-swift/29789195#29789195).

You need to add all these frameworks and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by force loading the Google Maps framework:

```
force_load <path/to/GoogleMapsSDK/GoogleMaps.framework>
```

I'm still unsure why adding the Facebook SDK failed to resolve the Mach-O errors, but my brain is too fried to care at the present time.

Thanks for the help!